# Get line of a specific word in TextView | ANDROID

Tags: android, scrollview, getline, scrollto

I have the following problem: 
I have a TextView and there's a text from a StringBuilder with a word that is marked and this word is defined as a StringArray.

Now the problem is that **I don't know how to get the line of this specific word.**

I know there's this method to go to a specific line:

```
        scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int y = textView.getLayout().getLineTop(0); //That's the line where the view goes to
                scrollView.scrollTo(0, y);
            }
        });
```

Now I want that the view doesn't go to a specific line, rather that the view should go to a specific line which is mutable with the word.

Is there a command like "getLineTop", so that's not a line rather a word?

Thanks

---

**EDIT**

```
    int total = 0;
    String word_search = Etxt.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    String fullTxt = textView.getText().toString();
    String[] array = fullTxt.split("\n");
    final String[] markiert = new String[array.length];
    String word;
    StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        word = array[i];
        if (word.toLowerCase().contains(word_search)) {
            markiert[i] = word.trim();
            st.append("<b><i><font color=\"#035525\">" + markiert[i] + "</font></i></b>");
            total++;
        } else {
            st.append(word);
        }
        st.append("<br>");
    }
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("" + st));
    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                int indexOfWord = textView.getText().toString().indexOf(markiert[0]);
                int line = textView.getLayout().getLineForOffset(indexOfWord);
                int y = textView.getLayout().getLineTop(line);
                scrollView.scrollTo(0, y);
        }
    });
```

That's the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the method [getLineForOffset(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html#getLineForOffset(int)):

> Get the line number on which the specified text offset appears.

So now all you need is the start index of the marked word.
You may already have this available, or you could do a simple indexOf lookup.
Alternatively you could use [Spannable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html) to mark (and style) the word.

---

Used like:

```
String wordToLookFor = "Hello";
int indexOfWord = textView.getText().toString().indexOf(wordToLookFor);
int lineNumber = textView.getLayout().getLineForOffset(index);
```

---

**Edit**
Try something like

```
    String textToFind = Etxt.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    String fullTxt = textView.getText().toString();

    SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(fullTxt);

    final int index = fullTxt.indexOf(textToFind);
    if(index == -1) {
        // text does not contain the word
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text '" + textToFind + "' not found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else {
        int lineNum = textView.getLayout().getLineForOffset(index);
        int lineStart = textView.getLayout().getLineEnd(lineNum -1);
        int lineEnd = textView.getLayout().getLineEnd(lineNum);
        // set style to the entire line, as your origional code
        spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#035525")), lineStart, lineEnd, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC), lineStart, lineEnd, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        textView.setText(spannable);
        textView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int line = textView.getLayout().getLineForOffset(index);
                int y = textView.getLayout().getLineTop(line);
                scrollView.scrollTo(0, y);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't know what you mean with indexOf lookup. Can you code an example for me? Thanks

Comment: Alright. But for the full example, you say the *word is defined as a StringArray*. How does this work? In the end you will need just a single String which represents the actual text to scroll to.

Comment: No, forget this with the String Array :). How I must define the variable index? Can you make a short full example for me? Thanks

Comment: Yes check the edit. And please be sure to accept if it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks! But this doesn't work. Do you know what's the problem?

Comment: Of course I check your answer if it's correct!!! But there's a problem. That doesn't work

Comment: Hm. What doesn't work? Do you get a correct line number? Log or debug that to see if it makes sense. Note that if the text does not contain the word you look for it will report line 0

Comment: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int java.lang.String.count' on a null object reference" Thats the error

Comment: Do you have an idea how to solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: Yes the word you pass to the indexOf method is null, which is the word to look for. This is out of scope of the question, but so you'll need to post more code to help. Specifically the part where you parse or define the word that you want to find.

Comment: I edited the question with the code. It's very long. That's a method to search in a TextView

Comment: I see you edited markiert[1] with markiert[0], which I was going to suggest. Does it help?

Comment: No, I tried this, but didn't help. Do you find the mistake? Thanks

Comment: Also, you still need the call to getLineTop():          
int line = textView.getLayout().getLineForOffset(indexOfWord);
int y = textView.getLayout().getLineTop(line);

Comment: I changed this in my question under "edit". Do you mean this? That doesn't work too. Thanks

Comment: Do you have another idea how to solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad it worked out. Even though in the end it was very out of scope of the original question :p

Comment: Hahah yes. Thanks for your time